# Laravel modal binding gives route not found error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I'm developing simple crude application using laravel 4.2. this is my controller method for edit/update.

```
class ProductsController extends BaseController{

    public function getEdit($id){

       $product=Products::find($id);
       $this->layout->content=View::make('products.edit',compact('product'));   
   }
}
```

this is the part of edit.blade.php file

```
 {{ Form::model($product, ['route' => ['products/update', $product->id], 'method' => 'patch']) }}
```

I define route for the ProductsController  as follows in route.php file

```
 Route::controller ( 'products', 'ProductsController');
```

when i try to edit product(http://localhost:8000/products/5/edit)

it says **Route [products/update] not defined.**

this is my edit link

```
 <a class="btn btn-small btn-info" href="{{ URL::to('products/' . $product->id . '/edit') }}">Edit </a>
```

what is the reason for this error? i have define patchUpdate() function on product contraller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a route controller, not a resourceful controller - so there are no 'named' routes.

You could do this

```
{{ Form::model($product, ['action' => 'ProductsController@putEdit', $product->id], 'method' => 'patch']) }}
```

Comment: I tried with products.update. but then it says  "Controller method not found"           browser link is http://localhost:8000/products/3/edit

Comment: yes agree with @TheShiftExchange either use model route as mention below or resource route

Comment: still gives same error  "Controller method not found" .is my routing Url correct?  http://localhost:8000/products/2/edit

Answer (score 1):

Add following line your routes.php file

```
Route::model('products', 'Product');
Route::resource('products', 'ProductsController');
```

and also change what @The Shift Exchange has suggested

```
products.update not products/update
```

change also

```
 <a class="btn btn-small btn-info" href="{{ URL::to('products/getEdit/'. $product->id) }}">Edit </a>
```

Comment: still gives same error  "Controller method not found" .is my routing Url correct?  http://localhost:8000/products/2/edit

Comment: just edited answer. have you pur above code in routes.php file

Comment: also change  <a class="btn btn-small btn-info" href="{{ URL::to('products/edit/'. $product->id) }}">Edit </a>

Comment: changed every thing mentioned. but it does not working

Comment: have you created method edit or putEdit suggested by me and TheShiftExchange where you will put your update code

Comment: change edit to getEdit ('products/getEdit/'. $product->id) if you want to redirect to same method